# Get a sub HTTP header of a multipart/form-data request in System.Web.HttpRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http-headers, httprequest

I'm located in the code behind of a .NET WebForm page.
I have access to the HTTP request received from the client via the object System.Web.HttpRequest.

I had no problem to "parse" the entire HTTP request (request.Headers, request.ContentType, request.Querystring, request.Forms, etc...) but in a context of a request sent by the client which is a multipart/form-data request, I didn't find any way to get the sub HTTP header (the content type) of my payload in the example below: **Content-Type: application/xml**.

Does someone know how to get it ?
FYI, I want to get the content type of the payload because it could be in JSON or XML.

```
POST https://<my_url> HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------195936636192145509880883
Content-Length: 34247

----------------------------195936636192145509880883
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xml_payload"
Content-Type: application/xml

<test_root>
    <test_node>
        <test_field1>TEST1</test_field1>
        <test_field2>TEST 1</test_field2>
        <test_field3>02/03/2020</test_field3>
    </test_node>
</test_root>
----------------------------195936636192145509880883
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BlankPdf1"; filename="BlankPdf.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.4
<binary_file>
%%EOF----------------------------195936636192145509880883
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BlankPdf2"; filename="BlankPdf2.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.4
<binary_file>
%%EOF----------------------------195936636192145509880883
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BlankPdf3"; filename="BlankPdf3.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.4
<binary_file>
%%EOF----------------------------195936636192145509880883--
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the content type.